# How to set selection in UITextView?

Tags: ios, uitableview, uitextview

I have an `UITextView` which is placed inside the `UITableViewCell`. To select the content inside the `UITextView`, I'll use the following code.

```
[UITextView select:self];
[UITextView setSelectedRange:NSMakeRange(start,length)];
```

Once the `UITableView` get loaded, following methods get called

1. `numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section`
2. `cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath`
3. `heightForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath`

My question is , Where should i place this code to get the `UITextView` got focused.

Thanks for your answers.

Comment: call - (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath  by passing indexPath...then do your stuff in this method.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should put the code in the `viewDidAppear` method. First, scroll the target cell into the view to make it visible:

```
scrollToRowAtIndexPath:atScrollPosition:animated:
```

Then, get the cell into which you want to direct the input:

```
cellForRowAtIndexPath:
```

Now cast the cell to the cell of your type, grab its `UITextView`, make a selection, and finally give it focus.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you have implemented

```
<UITextFieldDelegate>
```

Then following methods will be called

```
-(void) textFieldDidEndEditing:(UITextField *)textField {

}

-(void) textFieldDidBeginEditing:(UITextField *)textField {

}
```

But you must set

```
textFiled.delegate = self;
```

Answer (score 0):

If I understood your problem correctly,

If you want to focus the textView on launch then you need to place the code inside `cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath`  because you are adding the UITextView to UITableViewCell and the tableView cell is created/reused inside that dataSource methods.

And if you want it to focus on tapping of the row then make use of

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath;
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks for your info. My aim is to focus the textview once it got loaded. And , Not while the row got tapped.

Comment: Then you can have it inside `cellForRowAtIndexPath:` delegate method